# Clicking the "Show more" link on a LinkedIn group page using Ruby Mechanize

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I have logged in to Linkedin and reached my groups page using Ruby Mechanize. I am also able to retrieve the list of questions on the page. However, I am unable to click the "Show more" link at the bottom so that I can the entire page and hence all the questions:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'open-uri'

a = Mechanize.new { |agent|
  # LinkedIn probably refreshes after login
  agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
}

a.get('http://linkedin.com/') do |home_page|
    my_page = home_page.form_with(:name => 'login') do |form|
    form.session_key  = '********'   #put you email ID
    form.session_password = '********'  #put your password here
  end.submit

mygroups_page = a.click(my_page.link_with(:text => /Groups/))

#puts mygroups_page.links

link_to_analyse = a.click(mygroups_page.link_with(:text => 'Semantic Web'))

link_to_test = link_to_analyse.link_with(:text => 'Show more...')

puts link_to_test.class

# link_to_analyse.search(".user-contributed .groups a").each do |item|

#   puts item['href']

#  end

end
```

Although a link exists with text 'Show more...' in the page, I am somehow not able to click it.the link_to_test.class shows NilClass What is the possible problem?

```
The part of the page I need to reach is:
<div id="inline-pagination">
        <span class="running-count">20</span>
        <span class="total-count">1134</span>
            <a href="groups?mostPopularList=&amp;gid=49970&amp;split_page=2&amp;ajax=ajax" class="btn-quaternary show-more-comments" title="Show more...">
              <span>Show more...</span>
              <img src="http://static01.linkedin.com/scds/common/u/img/anim/anim_loading_16x16.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="">
            </a>
      </div>
```

I need to click the show more... I can use links_with(:href => ..) but doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tags inside the anchor will create some white space around the anchor text. You can account for that with:

```
link_to_analyse.link_with :text => /\A\s*Show more...\s*\Z/
```

But it's probably good enough to just do:

```
link_to_analyse.link_with :text => /Show more.../
```

Answer (score 1):

**NEW ANSWER:**

I just inspected the page source of the group and it seems that for the "Show more" link they actually use the three full stop characters and not an ellipsis.

Have you tried targeting the link by it's `title` attribute?

```
link_to_analyse.link_with(:title => 'Show more...')
```

If that's still not working, have you tried dumping the text of all the links on the page with

```
link_to_analyse.links.each do |link|
  puts link.text
end
```

**---- OLD ANSWER INCORRECT ----**

LinkedIn use the "Horizontal Ellipsis" Unicode  character (code U+2026) for their links that "look" like they have "..." at the end. So your code is not actually finding the link.

Character you need: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm

Sneaky :)

EDIT: and to get the link ofcourse you need to insert an appropriate Unicode character in your link text like so:

```
link_to_analyse.link_with(:text => 'Show more\u2026')
```

Comment: How do I find this link and click it in that case, using Mechanize?